# WinUI3 does not support the Background Property of AcrylicBrush in C++ desktop development. Is there any alternative way of doing it?

Tags: c++, xaml, winui-3

WinUI3 does not support the Background Property of AcrylicBrush in C++ desktop development. WindowsAppSDK version "1.0.0", but the property exists in UWP c++ and C# universal development, Is there any alternative way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It is available in the latest preview release.

https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/preview-channel#version-11-preview-3-110-preview3

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7061

Comment: I tried to update WindowsAppSDK to 1.1.0 Preview 3 but still can't use Background Acrylic in C++ desktop development